# Can a Gtk.Entry (part of a Gtk.SpinButton) "have-focus" if it's in a Gtk.Menu?

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, widget, focus, gtk3

I'm making an application that can change certain parameters through a `Gtk.Menu`. I have a `Gtk.MenuButton` that pops down a `Gtk.Menu` with other submenus in it. One of those submenus has `Gtk.MenuItems` with `Gtk.SpinButtons` in them. I have gotten the `Gtk.SpinButtons` to receive input by bringing their associated `Gdk.Windows` to the front of the Z-order with `Gdk.Window.show()`, but I can't get the `Gtk.Entry` part of the `Gtk.SpinButton` to receive keyboard focus.

I have tried to use `Gtk.Widget.grab_focus()` and other related methods to no avail. It does highlight the `Gtk.Entry` text, and I can type in new text, but if I click away or press enter, it doesn't actually update/change the `Gtk.SpinButton` value. I have connected to the "change-value" and "value-changed" signals but typing anything into the `Gtk.SpinButton` doesn't fire them.

I've found out that a widget can be the "focus widget" but not have the "global input focus" if its toplevel `Gtk.Window` doesn't also have the global focus. Therefore, I'm stuck. Is there any way around this? Can I make the `Gtk.SpinButton` entry field have the keyboard focus if it's in a `Gtk.Menu`?

Here is a minimal example:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

class Menu(Gtk.Menu):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Menu.__init__(self)
        menu_item = Gtk.MenuItem(label="Submenu")
        menu_item2 = Gtk.MenuItem(label="Item")
        self.append(menu_item)
        self.append(menu_item2)

        submenu = Gtk.Menu()
        sub_mi = Gtk.MenuItem()
        spin_button = Gtk.SpinButton()
        spin_adj = Gtk.Adjustment(value=0,lower=0, upper=10, step_increment=1)
        spin_button.set_adjustment(spin_adj)
        sub_mi.add(spin_button)
        submenu.append(sub_mi)
        menu_item.set_submenu(submenu)

        spin_button.connect("realize", self.on_realize)
        spin_button.connect("map-event", self.on_map_event)
        submenu.connect("button-release-event", self.on_button_release)
        submenu.connect("enter-notify-event", self.on_enter)

        self.show_all()

    def on_realize(self, spin_button):
        spin_button.add_events(Gdk.EventMask.STRUCTURE_MASK)

    def on_map_event(self, spin_button, event):
        for win in spin_button.get_window().get_children():
            win.show()

    def on_button_release(self, menu, event):
        return True

    def on_enter(self, menu, event):
        mouse = event.get_device()
        mouse.ungrab(event.time)

win = Gtk.Window()
win.set_default_size(100, 20)
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
mb = Gtk.MenuButton()
win.add(mb)
menu = Menu()
mb.set_popup(menu)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is convoluted, and there's probably a better solution (like not using a `Gtk.Menu` for this...), but I've come up with a workaround anyway.

Since I can't activate or fully focus the `Gtk.SpinButton` I am just forcing it to update the text field whenever there is a `leave-notify-event` fired from it.

```
spin_button.connect("leave-notify-event", self.on_leave)

def on_leave(self, spin_button, event):
    value = spin_button.get_text()
    spin_button.set_value(float(value))
    spin_button.update()
```

Comment: And yes, I realize I have to catch the case where the `spin_button.update()` fails.